# How to enable UI Theme Support in QGIS 2.12?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.12

According to the [2.12 Changelog](http://changelog.qgis.org/qgis/version/2.12.0/) QGIS now ships with a *light* and a *dark* UI Theme. A longer description of the UI themes can be found at [Nathan Woodrows blog on QGIS UI themes](http://nathanw.net/2015/08/29/ui-theme-support-now-core-in-qgis/).

However, when I install QGIS 2.12.0-1 via OSGeo4W there is only the option to choose the *default* theme.

Does anybody know whether there is another option I am missing to enable the dark theme?

[image]

---

Edit:

According to the [QGIS repository](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/resources/themes/Night%20Mapping) the Theme should be saved under `QGIS/ressources/themes`. I am missing said `themes` folder even after a re-install and a fresh install of QGIS 2.12 from OSGeo4W.

Edit2:

[Nathan Woodrow confirmed it as a bug](https://twitter.com/madmanwoo/status/658739128322752512) and is on it. In the meantime I copied the themes folder, like @Mapperz suggested, and everything looks great now.

Edit3:

Annnnnd it is [fixed](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/3e8caa9a1cea3495391ab158d87935471a78e965). That was fast!

Comment: I have asked the core programmer https://twitter.com/mapperz/status/658695217797664769

Comment: on windows 7 (pro) themes folder does not exist either C:\Program Files\QGIS Lyon\apps\qgis\resources

Comment: Where I have to adjust the color setting in the Night Mapping theme to make the description text from black (unreadable) to white?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Worked this out - the theme folders are missing from the release for the QGIS UI Themes.

I created the folders and copied the files from 
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/resources

restarted QGIS and the Night Mapping Theme is now available.

[image]

I would class this as a bug in the first release of QGIS 2.12

Comment: Yeah looks like a bug.

Comment: Did that as well after finding the folder on Github. You beat me to the answer. Accepted as solved for future reference, until this is fixed with the next release.

Comment: Fix in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/3e8caa9a1cea3495391ab158d87935471a78e965

Comment: As well as following @mapperz instructions, I had to copy the `themes` directory and `symbology-ng-style.db` and `symbology-ng-style.xml` to my `.qgis2` directory in my home folder. Then the Night Mapping theme was picked up. Thanks to @nathan-w for the tip! [link](https://twitter.com/SamRFranklin/status/661467334704390144)

Answer (score 2):

To change the User Interface (UI) for QGIS the 'Load QSS' Plugin is required

Here is an example in QGIS 2.12

[image]

There are 8 themes currently (restart of QGIS is not required)
[image]

Plugin link
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LoadQSS/

Comment: +1, However, while this is a nice plugin it completely contradicts the Changelog("By default we ship with two themes: Default and Night mapping.") and the [QGIS respository master](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/resources/themes/Night%20Mapping) which lists `Night Mapping` as a theme that is shipped with QGIS.

Comment: @Kersten it may a bug preventing the activation, this version of QGIS has only just been released. Though this is the only way I have made UI changes in previous versions.