# Where are the button icons stored in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gui

I'm trying to create a custom icon theme to make my install of QGIS a bit nicer, but I can't find where the icons are stored. All I've found is the QGIS logo in /usr/share/qgis/images/icons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are being packed into the application during the compilation phase.

You can find them at the source unpacked:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/images/themes/default

Edit:

QGis 2.12 and up supports (?) themes. I suspect you want to create your own theme based on the default pack. You can find more info at :

[How to enable UI Theme Support in QGIS 2.12?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167798/how-to-enable-ui-theme-support-in-qgis-2-12)

Comment: Would the only solution be to replace the icons in the source package and then recompile?

Comment: No, that's the whole point of themes. Check the answer in the edit, it gives pointers on how to create your own theme with custom icons and all. :)

Comment: Note: That bug has been fixed in 2.12.1 so it would work out the box right now.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you won't find qgis icon set in image format file within your installation. To see and change the icons, you need access to the source code and then compile it yourself.

All qgis source code is in github:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS

Icons are in the images folder:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/images/themes/default

Information on how to compile QGIS source code can be found here:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL